# org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested Exception in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm facing a problem with arguments that are defined in **sendGet** Method, it receives  stream as xml file from ftp server. For listening the coming stream I'm using **Spring cloud stream** by binding the class **SpringIntegrationTransformer**  to **Processor.class**.Here is my piece of code.

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
    public class SpringIntegrationTransformer {
        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringIntegrationTransformer.class);
        @Autowired
        private PolicyListMapper policyListMapper;

        @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
        @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
        public MessageSource<byte[]> sendGet(Message<byte[]> message) throws Exception {
            byte[] data=message.getPayload();
            logger.info("Got data = " + data);
            byte[] processedMessage=processData(data);
            return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(processedMessage).build();

        }


    private byte[] processData(byte[] data) {

        if (data.length == 0) {
            logger.info("Empty data");
            return new byte[0];
        }
        try {
            logger.info("Contrat.xml data : " + new String(data, "UTF-8"));
            return runEmployeeUnmarshaller(data);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            logger.error("Error processData" + e);
        }

        return new byte[0];

    }

     private byte[] runEmployeeUnmarshaller(byte[] data) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PolicyList.class);
            ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            ClassLoader classLoader = RxJavaTransformer.class.getClassLoader();
            InputStream xsdStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("policies.xsd");
            StreamSource xsdSource = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsdSource);

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

            PolicyList policyList = (PolicyList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(input);
            logger.info("PolicyList data : " + policyList == null ? "not marshalled " : "marshalled");

            // TODO Add map struct to convert the object
            PolicyListDto policyListDto = policyListMapper.mapObjectToDto(policyList);
            byte[] policyListByte = SerializationUtils.serialize(policyListDto);
            return policyListByte;

        } catch (JAXBException | SAXException e) {
            logger.error("Error runEmployeeUnmarshaller" + e);
        }
        return new byte[0];

    }
}
```

the sendGet method is responsible for receiving stream from ftp server and then convert it to **DTO** class **policyListDto** then transforming it to byte[] by **processData** method.

When executing the class I note that build is successful but when I deploy the microservice in spring cloud and putting the xml file in ftp server, I get this error as below:

```
> 2018-10-18 12:58:38.408 ERROR 1256 --- [ftp.FTPSTREAM-1]
> o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   :
> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown
> while invoking
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer#sendGet[1
> args]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
> not serialize object of type: class
> org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto, failedMessage=GenericMessage
> [payload=byte[2273], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT,
> amqp_receivedExchange=FTPSTREAM.ftp, amqp_deliveryTag=6,
> file_name=contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie - Copie2.xml,
> deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=FTPSTREAM.ftp.FTPSTREAM,
> amqp_redelivered=false,
> file_originalFile=\tmp\rxjava\contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie -
> Copie2.xml, file_relativePath=contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie -
> Copie2.xml, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=FTPSTREAM.ftp,
> id=cb05aca3-6202-0ac7-d027-e95b468909fe,
> amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-GZZjbfJ-TFeQ8VYiDaCypw,
> contentType=application/octet-stream, timestamp=1539863915387}]   at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:63)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
>   at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
>   at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
>   at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
>   at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:60)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:214)
>   at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
>   at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:211)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77)
>   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object of
> type: class org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
> org.proactive.utils.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:34)
>   at
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer.runEmployeeUnmarshaller(SpringIntegrationTransformer.java:84)
>   at
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer.processData(SpringIntegrationTransformer.java:54)
>   at
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer.sendGet(SpringIntegrationTransformer.java:41)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
>   at
> org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>   at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
>   ... 27 more Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
> org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>   at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>   at
> org.proactive.utils.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:32)
>   ... 36 more
> 
> 2018-10-18 12:58:38.409  WARN 1256 --- [ftp.FTPSTREAM-1]
> o.s.a.r.r.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer  : Retries exhausted for
> message (Body:'[B@7914e278(byte[2273])' MessageProperties
> [headers={file_name=contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie - Copie2.xml,
> file_originalFile=\tmp\rxjava\contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie -
> Copie2.xml, contentType=application/octet-stream,
> file_relativePath=contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie - Copie2.xml},
> contentType=application/octet-stream, contentLength=0,
> receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false,
> receivedExchange=FTPSTREAM.ftp, receivedRoutingKey=FTPSTREAM.ftp,
> deliveryTag=6, consumerTag=amq.ctag-GZZjbfJ-TFeQ8VYiDaCypw,
> consumerQueue=FTPSTREAM.ftp.FTPSTREAM])
> 
> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown
> while invoking
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer#sendGet[1
> args]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
> not serialize object of type: class
> org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:63)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:60)
> ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:214)
> [spring-integration-amqp-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
> [spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]     at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
> [spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]     at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:211)
> [spring-integration-amqp-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181] Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object of
> type: class org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
> org.proactive.utils.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:34)
> ~[proactive-utils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer.runEmployeeUnmarshaller(SpringIntegrationTransformer.java:84)
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer.processData(SpringIntegrationTransformer.java:54)
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer.sendGet(SpringIntegrationTransformer.java:41)
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
> org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]  ... 27
> common frames omitted Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
> org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
> ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
> ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
> org.proactive.utils.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:32)
> ~[proactive-utils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    ... 36 common
> frames omitted
> 
> 2018-10-18 12:58:38.410  WARN 1256 --- [ftp.FTPSTREAM-1]
> s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message
> listener failed.
> 
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException:
> Listener threw exception  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1417)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181] Caused by:
> org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send
> Message to channel 'FTPSTREAM.ftp.FTPSTREAM.errors'; nested exception
> is
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException:
> Retry Policy Exhausted    at
> org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:163)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:475)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:98)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.integration.support.ErrorMessagePublisher.publish(ErrorMessagePublisher.java:164)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.recover(ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.java:83)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512)
> ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]    at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:351)
> ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]    at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
> ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]    at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:211)
> ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    ... 8 common
> frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException:
> Retry Policy Exhausted    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer.recover(RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer.java:45)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder$3.handleMessage(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:513)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>   at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]  ... 21
> common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException:
> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown
> while invoking
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer#sendGet[1
> args]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
> not serialize object of type: class
> org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto, failedMessage=GenericMessage
> [payload=byte[2273], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT,
> amqp_receivedExchange=FTPSTREAM.ftp, amqp_deliveryTag=6,
> file_name=contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie - Copie2.xml,
> deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=FTPSTREAM.ftp.FTPSTREAM,
> amqp_redelivered=false,
> file_originalFile=\tmp\rxjava\contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie -
> Copie2.xml, file_relativePath=contrat_valid_TEST_amine - Copie -
> Copie2.xml, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=FTPSTREAM.ftp,
> id=cb05aca3-6202-0ac7-d027-e95b468909fe,
> amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-GZZjbfJ-TFeQ8VYiDaCypw,
> contentType=application/octet-stream, timestamp=1539863915387}]   ...
> 27 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown
> while invoking
> org.proactive.policy.collector.SpringIntegrationTransformer#sendGet[1
> args]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
> not serialize object of type: class
> org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:63)
```

So I'm assuming that error comes from **sendGet**'s argument and I modified the **byte[]** type to **Message** as shown in the above code , but without success.

Please I'm thankful for any help.Thanks in advance for resolving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem in your code...

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object of
> type: class org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
> org.proactive.utils.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:34)
>...
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
> org.proactive.policy.dto.PolicyListDto    at
```

In future; post the stack trace without modifying it; it's hard to read when mis-formatted (simply indent it by 4 bytes with Command-K).